# Accessing an Internal REST API via OAuth 2.0 from Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am building a Spring Boot application that consists of a web app as well as a REST-based API.  The web app is secured using Spring Security.  Data is obtained by the web app by invoking the REST-based API via a series of AJAX requests.

As external clients may also use the REST services, I have secured them using OAuth 2.0.  I have set up OAuth 2.0 to use the password grant type.

While I can successfully access the REST services using a third-party tool (i.e. Postman), I'm struggling with what to do with accessing the REST services using the AJAX calls.  I've built logic that gets the access token when the user has successfully logged into the web app.  I need to pass that access token as part of the Authorization header, but it seems as though there should be an easier way than to pass this token in each and every AJAX request.

I was thinking of delegating each AJAX request to an instance of the OAuth2RestTemplate class which would get the access token from the user information and then invoke the appropriate service call.  But that doesn't seem any less complex.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of scenario?